# ionic build --prod error: The pipe 'safe2' could not be found

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic4

Everything works perfectly fine when I do `ionic serve`.

I have a **viewReport** page, which opens a modal, named **viewModal** page.

I created a pipe, when I called that pipe in viewModal.module.ts, it was giving error. Someone from Stack Overflow guided me to add it in the viewReport.module.ts page. I did it and it worked.

But now when I am making a production build using `ionic build --prod`, it is giving error:

```
ERROR in The pipe 'safe2' could not be found ("
    <ion-text>
      {{daily_report_desc }}
      <span [innerHtml]="[ERROR ->]daily_report_desc | safe2: 'html'">{{daily_report_desc}}</span>
      </ion-text>
    <ion-text>
")

[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ng.

...
```

Code of `viewReport.module.ts`

```
import { Safe2Pipe } from './../pipes/safepipe2/safe2.pipe';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    ViewdailyreportPageRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [ViewdailyreportPage,ShortenPipe,ViewdreportmodalPage,SafePipe,Safe2Pipe],
  entryComponents: [ViewdreportmodalPage],
  exports:[Safe2Pipe]
})
export class ViewdailyreportPageModule {}
...
```

Code of `viewModal.page.html`

```
<ion-text>
  {{daily_report_desc }}
  <span [innerHtml]="daily_report_desc | safe2: 'html'">{{daily_report_desc}}</span>
</ion-text>
```

Everything working fine with `ionic serve` but gives error with `ionic build --prod`.

### Edit 1

Added safe2pipe in app.module.ts, see below image , now when I open **viewReport** page (which opens **viewModal** page), it gives error -

```
"): ng:///ViewReportPageModule/ViewModalPage.html@18:25
The pipe 'safe2' could not be found ("
    <ion-text>
      {{daily_report_desc }}
      <span [innerHtml]="[ERROR ->]daily_report_desc | safe2: 'html'">{{daily_report_desc}}</span>
      </ion-text>
```

[image]

[image]

### Edit 2

Code of `safe2pipe.ts`

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml, SafeStyle, SafeScript, SafeUrl, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'safe2'
})
export class Safe2Pipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(protected sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

 public transform(value: any, type: string): SafeHtml | SafeStyle | SafeScript | SafeUrl | SafeResourceUrl {
    switch (type) {
            case 'html': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
            case 'style': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value);
            case 'script': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript(value);
            case 'url': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value);
            case 'resourceUrl': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);
            default: throw new Error(`Invalid safe type specified: ${type}`);
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using the [innerHtml] input to apply your pipe?

Comment: because its wysiwyg editor, to see the text with html properties

Comment: Do you have a module for your pipe?

Comment: no i have `safe2.pipe.ts` and `safe2.spec.pipe.ts`

Comment: Try this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-g2bbaz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts if it works I will make an answer.

Comment: you need to open modal from `app.component.html` and call ` {{text | parsechar:10}}` on its html and check.

Comment: If you add the pipe to app.module.ts does it work? I think that you are adding the pipe to the wrong module.

Comment: let me try that and come back

Comment: I have done as guided by you, it is giving error, see `Edit:: 1`, i have updated the question with error image

Comment: Ok, the problem is not on the importing part. Do your pipe have this line "@Pipe({name: 'safe2'})"

Comment: updated the question, see code of `safe2pipe.ts` code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214329/discussion-between-igor-and-user2828442).

Comment: please update stackblitz with modal, i have deleted my modal, will try to do it your way as discussed

Comment: Ok, i will do on stackblitz as we discussed

Comment: thanks, i am waiting, if possible,do write in answer, what to add in `app.module.ts` and in what to add in module.ts of parent page or modal page

Comment: created new modal page, called its module in app.module.ts , pipe in modal page's module.ts , everything worked, you can post this as an answer..cheers

Answer (score 0):

Here is the stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-c7zfbm

The steps are:

- Create Modal (with module)
- Import pipe on Modal Module
- Import modal module on app.module
- Put the modal page on entryComponents of app.module.
- Call the pipe on the modal html

Please note that the stackblitz for ionic is outdated and to work I made some workarounds. To see the content, inspect and look for the html code.